# How to get Find Next to work on non-standard extensions in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to edit some files in Eclipse with extensions like .page and .component.  Everything seems to work ok in the editor, expect Find Next does not respond to F3.  In fact, the menu doesn't even list the shortcut whenI am editing a .page or .component file (screenshot below).

So how do I make Eclipse do Find Next on F3 for these extensions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Eclipse FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_my_own_key-binding_configuration%3F):

> To see the current key configuration and its keyboard shortcuts, choose the `Window > Preferences` menu command to open the Eclipse workbench Preferences. Select the `General > Editor > Keys` page. This page displays the currently active Scheme (key configuration) and the keyboard shortcuts it defines. Emacs is a set of keyboard shortcuts that emulates emacs. Similarly, Microsoft Visual Studio defines a set of shortcuts that emulates that IDE. The native configuration for Eclipse is Default.
>
> There are no APIs for defining key-binding configurations programmatically, but you can create them in a plug-in by using the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point. First, you need to define your new configuration:
>
> ```
> <keyConfiguration
>       name="My Configuration"
>       parent="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
>       description="This is a simple configuration"
>       id="org.eclipse.faq.sampleConfiguration">
>    </keyConfiguration>
> ```
>
> By specifying a parent, you are saying that your configuration should inherit key bindings from the parent unless they are explicitly set in your configuration. When key bindings are defined, they will refer to the configuration they belong to. If you write your own configuration, you’ll also need to define new key bindings for all the commands that you want to belong to your configuration.

See also [How do I provide a keyboard shortcut for my action?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F)

Comment: Hmmm, there is no file that defines what keys apply to what extensions?

Comment: @AngryHacker do you checked two links?

Comment: I did, but its asking me to create plugins...and its not very clear on how to do this...  From the above links - I couldn't tell (i am not eclipse expert - don't use it often).

Comment: @AngryHacker ok , so read this link i hope this link is usefully : 

vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html

Comment: Ahh, much better.  Thx.